# How to access a property of a service via a bound controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

I'm attempting to access a property of a service via a bound controller variable, within a template, to no success.

Controller:

```
app.controller('VictoryController', function($scope, AlertStatisticsService) {
    $scope.AlertStats = AlertStatisticsService;
});
```

Service returns an object structured like this:

```
factory = {
    factionWins = {
        vs: 123,
        nc: 123,
        tr: 123
    }
}
```

The template is rendered as part of an Attribute directive:

```
app.directive('homeVictoryCard', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope : {
            empire: '@',
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/home/partials/victory.card.html'
    };
});
```

Which is called by the following HTML element:

```
<div home-victory-card empire="vs"></div>
```

In the template in question, I'm attempting to access the controller / service's object data via the `empire` variable, which is in scope of the template, like so:

```
{{ AlertStats.factionWins[empire] }}
```

I'm also trying to use it in various ng-hide and ng-shows, like:

`ng-hide="AlertStats.factionWins[empire] > 0"`

In Twig, I used to use `attribute(AlertStats.factionWins, empire)` to grab the information, but I don't know how to do it in Angular, and Google searches haven't returned anything useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Syntax of snippets shown is all valid but snippets alone aren't complete enough to connect everything together. A simple demo that replicates problem would help

Comment: I'll see if I can get a codepen working

Comment: That being said ... `EMPIRE` doesn't appear to be a scope variable

Comment: I'll edit with further information

Comment: Added with further information, it's within a directive scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have directive with isolated scope it doesn't inherit scope from parent controller so `AlertStats` isn't in directive scope

You could inject the factory into directive or pass another scope variable as attribute to directive

Example injecting factory

```
app.directive('homeVictoryCard', function(AlertStatisticsService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope : {
            empire: '@',
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/home/partials/victory.card.html',
        link:function(scope){
           scope.AlertStats = AlertStatisticsService
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Thank you! I never knew you could inject into the directive's scope via that method.

Comment: Yes, can inject any service/factory or constant or provider ... simple example is `$http`